# PHP loop through 2 tables based position id and date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to loop through 2 tables (promotion and article).
The problem here is the promotion table. I want to display the promotion on a specific position. Eg. position 1 is the first position before the 1st article. And the article is ordered by newest date.

Table: promotion

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+
| id | promo       | postion | user | created_date        |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+
| 1  | promo 1     | 1       | 1    | 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+
| 2  | promo 2     | 4       | 1    | 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+
| 3  | promo 3     | 6       | 1    | 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------+
```

Table: article

```
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| id | article       | user | created_date        | public |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | article 1     | 1    | 2015-10-01 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 2  | article 2     | 1    | 2015-10-02 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 3  | article 3     | 1    | 2015-10-03 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 4  | article 4     | 1    | 2015-10-04 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 5  | article 5     | 1    | 2015-10-05 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 6  | article 6     | 1    | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | 0      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 7  | article 7     | 1    | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 8  | article 8     | 1    | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 9  | article 9     | 1    | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | 1      |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+--------+
```

Should look like this

```
<div>Promo 1</div>
    <div>Article 1</div>
    <div>Article 2</div>
    <div>Article 3</div>
<div>Promo 2</div>
    <div>Article 4</div>
    <div>Article 5</div>
<div>Promo 3</div>
    <div>Article 7</div>
    <div>Article 8</div>
    <div>Article 9</div>
```

So far I have this to display the article table

```
echo '<table>';

$dbList = dblink();
$sql = $dbList->prepare("SELECT article.* FROM article WHERE article.public = 1 ORDER BY date_created DESC");
$sql->execute();
while ($row = $sql->fetch()){

    echo '
        <tr>
            <td width="50">
                '.$row['id'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$row['article'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$row['date_created'].'
            </td>
            <td width="20" style="text-align: center;">
                '.$row['public'].'
            </td>
        </tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Please put up a clear question.

Comment: Hi Sajib, the problem is I don't know how solve the problem with the position. I was thinking of joining the promotion table into article, but I have no idea how to loop to both and display it the way I want it.

Comment: put promotion_id on article and use JOIN it seems like ONE TO MANY relation at least if article can have only 1 promotion

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to join tables, you can look into **MySQL JOIN** [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm). This is a simple tutorial for the same. You do not have to loop simultaneously through both the tables individually through your PHP script. Instead, use MySQL joins to join the two tables to create one single table on the fly and let your script loop through that single table in your code. This is how the problem you are facing is solved. I would prefer you do a little google search on MySQL joins as there are plenty of information already available on the web as well as here at SO.